# Ошибка при билде проекта [compressDebugAssets]

Tags: android, build

Возникает ошибка при билде нового проекта.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compressDebugAssets'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
   > D:\AndroidStudioProjects\HalloWorld\app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\out

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 14s
```

До этого ошибка имела следующий текст:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\AndroidStudioProjects\HalloWorld\app\build\intermediates\navigation_json\debug\navigation.json (Не удается найти указанный файл)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Для исправления ошибки я:

1. Переустанавливал Android Studio.
2. Выделил оперативную память.
3. Поставил gradle 7.

Comment: [Deprecated Gradle...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54619731)

Comment: Сделал так же, как и в том посте.
Ошибка не ушла
```A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest' (type 'ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest').

  - Type 'ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest' property 'mainMergedManifest' specifies file 'D:\AndroidStudioProjects\HalloWorld\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\out\AndroidManifest.xml' which doesn't exist.
```